# Write .doc file in android

Tags: android, ms-word, apache-poi

I'm trying to write a new word & excel file from my Android App. I used the Apache POI library. I was successful is creating the excel file without errors. I used HSSFWorkbook to create and populate the excel file. But while creating word file using XWPFDocument gives me a lot of errors and warnings. The error was XMLEventFactory classfile found missing. I tried to search all possible solutions in Google and ended up with the answer that, Android is missing few core JAVA libraries. Is there any other open source libraries to implement it or a better way to get this error fixed.

Answer (score 2):

With the XML based formats you will run into a few issues with bare Apache POI libraries, Android has some limitations and the XMLBeans jar file has duplicate class files among others.

There are currently at least two projects that wrap/adjust Apache POI for easier usage on Android:

1. https://github.com/andruhon/android5xlsx - provides pre-packaged libraries of Apache POI 3.12, a bit outdated by now
2. https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android/ - uses a different approach and allows to more easily re-build the packaged library with newer versions of Apache POI (this is mainted by me)

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your efforts.. but I saw your solution, in a similar kinda question and I tried using your poiShadow-all library. But it doesn't give me the solution. The package doesn't import the essential packages like    import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;                             So I couldn't use this package.

Comment: Some things are excluded in the default build-steps via "exclude" statements. Look at poishadow/build.gradle. You can remove any of those to get those code-pieces included as well.